# Как подключить существующий репозиторий к GitLab по ssh

Tags: ubuntu, git, ssh, gitlab, repository

Есть удаленный репозиторий доступ к которому осуществляется по ssh (git clone ssh://git@....)
Запустил у себя на сервере (Ubuntu 18) контейнер (Docker) с GitLab(EE).
Задача подключить удаленный репозиторий к Gitlab.
Через Web интерфейс такого функционала не вижу.

Comment: `$ git remote add ...` + `$ git push ...`

Comment: Вычитал про функцию зеркалирования репозиториев. 
Пытался сделать Mirror a repository через web интерфейс. Но у меня почему то Mirror direction только push и Authentification method: None или Password.

Если же я захожу на официальный портал Gitlab  и там создаю проект, то туда можно зеркалировать удаленный репозиторий и pull и push

Comment: Оказывается что Mirror direction - pull появляется только в платной версии gitlab. Все эти настройки находятся по пути: Project - Settings - Repository - Mirror a repository. (может кому пригодится)